# How to interact with mouse in Windows Form

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, mouseevent, mouse

I have a dictionary of buttons and also an null variable button. When you click on an button from the dictionary, we get the values ​​​​that should be sent to an empty variable.

```
public static Button selectedfigure=null;
public Dictionary<(int x, int y), Button> _Panels = new Dictionary<(int x, int y), Button>();

public void Fillboard()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
        {
            _Panels[(x, y)] = new Button()
            {
                Height = 64,
                Width = 64,
                Location = new Point(x * 64, y * 64),
                BackColor = CalculateBackColor(x,y),
                BackgroundImage = CalculateBackimage(x,y)               
            };
            Controls.Add(_Panels[(x, y)]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? If you want these buttons to do something, you'll need to wire up some `Click` handler(s). BTW, Whoever maintains this code will not appreciate you having a collection of Buttons named _Panels

Comment: Do look into Lambdas to create code for dynamically created controls..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is about **how to interact with Mouse** events on your "board". The answer is to subscribe to Mouse events like `Click` for each control you add. Your code is using a normal `Button` but will be much simpler if you make a custom class that *inherits* `Button` or preferably `PictureBox` and this way each instance keeps track of its own X-Y, color, and image.

Also, instead of using a `Dictionary` lookup and setting `Location` properties yourself, you might try an 8x8 `TableLayoutPanel` for the board, then iterate all its 8 columns and rows with methods that take `column` and `row` as arguments.

---

The mouse events can be subscribed to in the `addSquare` method.

```
private void addSquare(int column, int row)
{
    var color = ((column + row) % 2) == 0 ? Color.White : Color.Black;
    var square = new Square
    {
        BackColor = color,
        Column = column,
        Row = row,
        Size = new Size(80, 80),
        Margin = new Padding(0),
        Padding = new Padding(10),
        Anchor = (AnchorStyles)0xf,
        SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage,
    };
    tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(square, column, row);
    // Hook the mouse events here
    square.Click += onSquareClicked;
    square.MouseHover += onSquareMouseHover;
}
```

**Before and after iterating the `TableLayoutPanel` with `addSquare`**

[image: squares]

---

Changing the value of the `Square.Piece` property will choose an image from a resource file.

```
private void initImage(int column, int row)
{
    var square = (Square)tableLayoutPanel.GetControlFromPosition(column, row);
    if (square.BackColor == Color.Black)
    {
        switch (row)
        {
            case 0:
            case 1:
            case 2:
                square.Piece = Piece.Black;
                break;
            case 5:
            case 6:
            case 7:
                square.Piece = Piece.Red;
                break;
            default:
                square.Piece = Piece.None;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Before and after iterating the `TableLayoutPanel` with `initImage`**

[image: pieces]

---

`Mouse` event handlers are simple now:

```
private void onSquareMouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var square = (Square)sender;
    _tt.SetToolTip(square, square.ToString());
}
private void onSquareClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var square = (Square)sender;
    MessageBox.Show($"Clicked: {square}");
}
ToolTip _tt = new ToolTip();
```

[image: mouse events]

---

The `Square` class is uncomplicated, just a few lines of code.

```
class Square : PictureBox // Gives more visual control than Button
{
    public int Column { get; internal set; }
    public int Row { get; internal set; }
    Piece _piece = Piece.None;
    public Piece Piece
    {
        get => _piece;
        set
        {
            if(!Equals(_piece, value))
            {
                _piece = value;
                switch (_piece)
                {
                    case Piece.None:
                        Image = null;
                        break;
                    case Piece.Black:
                        Image = Resources.black;
                        break;
                    case Piece.Red:
                        Image = Resources.red;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public override string ToString() =>
        Piece == Piece.None ? 
            $"Empty {BackColor.Name} square [column:{Column} row:{Row}]" :
            $"{Piece} piece [column:{Column} row:{Row}]";
}
enum Piece { None, Black, Red };
```

---

**Edited (in response to Jeremy's excellent suggestion)**

*Where and how to call the methods to initialize the board:*

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // Board is a TableLayoutPanel 8 x 8
    tableLayoutPanel.AutoSize = true;
    tableLayoutPanel.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
    // Add squares
    IterateBoard(addSquare);
    // Add pieces
    IterateBoard(initImage);
}

void IterateBoard(Action<int, int> action)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < 8; column++)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++)
        {
            action(column, row);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/fill-board-8x8.git) this example.

Comment: Truly a great answer, one thing missing (for the newbies) is where you call `initImage`?

Comment: @JeremyThompson thanks 1e6 I made an edit using your suggestion and corrected a few glaring inaccuracies (haven't played _Checkers_ since I was 8!).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly which is your problem. I think you need know which button is pressed in your matrix.

You can add the controls in the same way but instead the use of `_Panels` dictionary, you can use `Tag` property of button to store a `Point` with the x,y coordinates:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
    {
        var button = new Button
        {
            Height = 64,
            Width = 64,
            Location = new Point(x * 64, y * 64),
            BackColor = CalculateBackColor(x,y),
            BackgroundImage = CalculateBackimage(x,y),                            
            Tag = new Point(x, y)
        };
        button.Click += OnButtonClick;
        Controls.Add(button);
    }
}
```

In the click event handler of the button:

```
private void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    var point = (Point)button.Tag;
    // Here you have x,y coordinates of clicked button
}
```