# How to get player's next move in c# WinForms without blocking the UI

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to write a chess program in C# Windows Forms and I am writing a method GetMove() in this HumanPlayer class I have, which will return the Move from a player input of two clicks on separate squares on the board UI.

Could I have some help / advice on what I should use to implement this or if I am misunderstanding something else, explain that to me.

I've tried to add code snippets, but please let me know if I've done them wrong.

```cs
    class HumanPlayer : Player
    {
        private Coords _selected;
        public HumanPlayer(PieceColour colour) : base(colour) 
        {
            _selected = new Coords();
        }

        public override ChessMove GetMove(Board board) 
        {
            Coords Start = new Coords();
            board.RaiseSquareClicked += ReceiveStartSquareClickInfo;
            // Want to wait until that function is triggered by the event until continuing
            Start = _selected;
            board.RaiseSquareClicked -= ReceiveStartSquareClickInfo;

            Coords End = new Coords();
            board.RaiseSquareClicked += ReceiveEndSquareClickInfo;
            // Want to wait until that function is triggered by the event until continuing
            End =  _selected;
            board.RaiseSquareClicked -= ReceiveEndSquareClickInfo;
            return new ChessMove(Start, End);
        }

        public void ReceiveStartSquareClickInfo(object sender, SquareClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            _selected = e.Square.Coords;
        }

        public void ReceiveEndSquareClickInfo(object sender, SquareClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            _selected = e.Square.Coords;
        }
    }
```

One thing I tried was using AutoResetEvent and WaitOne() and Set(), but this caused the UI to stop displaying.

I also tried to understand and use await and async, but I just confused myself and overcomplicated it and didn't get anywhere with it. So it might just be that I need someone to explain it to me.

This code that doesn't work might help someone understand what I misunderstand about asynchronous functions etc.

```cs
    public async void Play()
    {
        _currentPlayer = _players[0];
        _currentTurn = 1;
        while (!GameOver())
        {
            ChessMove move= await _currentPlayer.GetMove(_board);
            if (_currentPlayer == _players[1])
            {
                _currentTurn += 1;
                _currentPlayer = _players[0];
            }
            else
            {
                _currentPlayer = _players[1];
            }
        }
    }

    class HumanPlayer : Player
    {
        private Coords _selected;
        private TaskCompletionSource<bool> _squareClicked;
        public HumanPlayer(PieceColour colour) : base(colour) 
        {
            _selected = new Coords();
        }

        public override async Task<ChessMove> GetMove(Board board) 
        {
            Coords Start = new Coords();
            _squareClicked = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
            board.RaiseSquareClicked += ReceiveStartSquareClickInfo;
            _squareClicked.Task.Wait();
            Start = _selected;
            board.RaiseSquareClicked -= ReceiveStartSquareClickInfo;

            Coords End = new Coords();
            _squareClicked = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
            board.RaiseSquareClicked += ReceiveEndSquareClickInfo;
            _squareClicked.Task.Wait();
            End =  _selected;
            board.RaiseSquareClicked -= ReceiveEndSquareClickInfo;
            return new ChessMove(Start, End);
        }
        public async void ReceiveStartSquareClickInfo(object sender, SquareClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            _squareClicked.SetResult(true);
            _selected = e.Square.Coords;
        }

        public async void ReceiveEndSquareClickInfo(object sender, SquareClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            _squareClicked.SetResult(true);
            _selected = e.Square.Coords;
        }
    }
```

I've kinda been hesitant / nervous to post this question because I don't want people to get annoyed at me for posting a "duplicate question". Even though I've looked through several of the questions, it is confusing and frustrating not knowing whether the solution just doesn't apply to my situation or if I've added it in wrong. I'm sure I could find my solution answered in another question, but I feel it would take me a lot longer to find it and understand it than posting my own question.

Sorry if I've posted this question wrong or not followed the guidelines, this is my first post here.
If I've done anything wrong in formatting / communicating through this post, let me know and I'll try to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that you did some search and research before posting a question of your own! When you find an existing question that's similar but doesn't quite fit your case, it doesn't hurt to cite the link and say _I looked at [**link**] but I couldn't use the answer because [**reason**]._  By doing that you show you've made an effort to use the existing knowledge and it also helps people provide better answers for what you need. You shouldn't hesitate at that point ask for additional input to the problem. IMO you've made a really decent first post here no worries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question, from what I can understand, your wanting to wait on a response from another method before executing yours.

Using async/await is the best option for this, if your getting confused at that, there are some tutorials and such you can follow

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/
- https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/async-and-await-operator-in-csharp/

TaskCompletionSource is a class in C# that enables creating a Task object which can be manually completed with a result or exception.

```cs
class Example
{
    TaskCompletionSource<string> taskCompletionSource = new();
    
    public async Task DoStuff()
    {
        // Wait for the result of the TaskCompletionSource
        var result = await taskCompletionSource.Task;

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    public void SetResult(){
        taskCompletionSource.SetResult("Hello World!");
    }

}
```

In this example, calling to DoStuff method will wait until the SetResult method is called, which will then set the `result` variable to "Hello World!"

Comment: I am going to have a look at the links, is it ok if I wait until I've got it working before I mark it as solved?

Comment: Absolutely, let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 1):

Your post states that you want to **wait for another method to be triggered before continuing** and then describes three "states of play" so my first suggestion is to identify in code exactly the things we need to wait for in the chess game loop.

```
enum StateOfPlay
{
    PlayerChooseFrom,
    PlayerChooseTo,
    OpponentTurn,
}
```

---

**Game Loop**

The goal is to run a loop that cycles these three states continuously, waiting at each step. However, the main Form is always running its own Message Loop to detect mouse clicks and key presses and it's important not to block that loop with our own.

[image: game board]

---

The `await` keyword causes a waiting method to return *immediately* which allows the UI loop to keep running. But when "something happens" that we're waiting for, the execution of this method will *resume* on the next line after the `await`. A [semaphore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim) object says when to stop or go and is initialized here in the waiting state.

```
SemaphoreSlim _semaphoreClick= new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);
```

When the game board is clicked during the players turn then the `Release()` method will be called on the semaphore, allowing things to resume. In terms of the specific question that you asked, this code snippet shows how to use the `await` keyword in your chess game loop.

```
private async Task playGameAsync(PlayerColor playerColor)
{
    StateOfPlay = 
        playerColor.Equals(PlayerColor.White) ?
            StateOfPlay.PlayerChooseFrom :
            StateOfPlay.OpponentTurn;

    while(!_checkmate)
    {
        switch (StateOfPlay)
        {
            case StateOfPlay.PlayerChooseFrom:
                await _semaphoreClick.WaitAsync();
                StateOfPlay = StateOfPlay.PlayerChooseTo;
                break;
            case StateOfPlay.PlayerChooseTo:
                await _semaphoreClick.WaitAsync();
                StateOfPlay = StateOfPlay.OpponentTurn;
                break;
            case StateOfPlay.OpponentTurn:
                await opponentMove();
                StateOfPlay = StateOfPlay.PlayerChooseFrom;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Player's turn**

Here we have to wait for each square to get clicked. A straightforward way to do this is with a `SemaphoreSlim` object and call `Release()` when the game board is clicked during the player's turn.

```
Square _playerFrom, _playerTo, _opponentFrom, _opponentTo;

private void onSquareClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is Square square)
    {
        switch (StateOfPlay)
        {
            case StateOfPlay.OpponentTurn:
                // Disabled for opponent turn
                return;
            case StateOfPlay.PlayerChooseFrom:
                _playerFrom = square;
                Text = $"Player {_playerFrom.Notation} : _";
                break;
            case StateOfPlay.PlayerChooseTo:
                _playerTo = square;
                Text = $"Player {_playerFrom.Notation} : {_playerTo.Notation}";
                richTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.DarkGreen;
                richTextBox.AppendText($"{_playerFrom.Notation} : {_playerTo.Notation}{Environment.NewLine}");
                break;
        }
        _semaphoreClick.Release();
    }
}
```

---

**Opponents turn**

This simulates a computer opponent processing an algorithm to determine its next move.

```
private async Task opponentMove()
{
    Text = "Opponent thinking";
        
    for (int i = 0; i < _rando.Next(5, 10); i++)
    {
        Text += ".";
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
    string opponentMove = "xx : xx";
    Text = $"Opponent Moved {opponentMove}";
    richTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.DarkBlue;
    richTextBox.AppendText($"{opponentMove}{Environment.NewLine}");
}
```

It might be helpful to look at another answer I wrote that describes how to create the game board with a `TableLayoutPanel` and [how to interact with mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72959973/5438626) to determine the square that's being clicked on.

Comment: This is a really useful answer for my particular situation. I'm going to keep the first answer as the one that solved my problem because it is a more general solution, rather than specifically to my chess program. Thank you for this answer and I will also have a look at the other link you posted to see if I can adapt my current mouse interaction code. I will also keep your other advice in mind to in future link the answers that I had looked at previously.

Comment: Oh for sure! Also, here's the [repo](https://github.com/IVSoftware/async-chess-game-loop.git) that I used to test this answer if that would be helpful. It has the game board layout and the alternating chess clocks, for example.