# How to Get player's move in c# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have come across an issue involving a game where I need to get the player's move using a textbox and a button. The idea is that when the user enters something in the textbox and clicks the button, the value is then sent to a function that **waiting**.

**Allow me to explain further:**

the game is a two player game. one side is computer and the other side is the user.

*note that the winner() is a function which is my game's main algorithm and it's not necessary to explain it because the problem is something else

```
public void StartGame()
{
    string player;

    int cs = 0, ps = 0;

    //chooses the first player
    if (winer(n, 0) == true)
    {
        player = "computer";
    }
    else
    {
        player = "human";
    }

    while ( n > 0)
    {
        int move;
        move = 0;

        if (player == "computer")
        {
            lblTurn.Text = "Not Your Turn";


            //Computer's move

            for (global::System.Int32 i = z; i >= 1; i--)
            {

                Boolean breakit;
                breakit = false;

                if (i <= n)
                {
                    if (n % 2 == 1)
                    {
                        if (winer(n - i, cs % 2) == false)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(winer(n - i, cs % 2).ToString());
                            move = i;
                            breakit = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (cs % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            if (winer(n - i, 1) == false)
                            {
                                move = i;
                                breakit = true;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (winer(n - i, 0) == false)
                            {
                                move = i;
                                breakit = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (breakit)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            lbLog.Items.Add(string.Format($"The Computer takes {move} pebbles."));
            cs += move;
            lblComputersum.Text = string.Format($"Computer's Sum: {cs}");
        }
        else if (player == "human")
        {

            lblTurn.Text = "Your Turn";


            // Human's move

            if (n <= z)
            {
                lblMove.Text = "1 to " + n;
            }
            else
                lblMove.Text = "1 to " + z;


            //here is the problem:
            move = ?;

            lbLog.Items.Add(string.Format($"The Player takes {move} pebbles."));
            ps += move;
            lblPlayerSum.Text = string.Format($"Players's Sum: {ps}");
        }


        // Update the game state
        n = n - move;
        ds = false;
        // Switch players
        if (player == "computer")
        {
            player = "human";
        }
        else
        {
            player = "computer";
        }

    }

    // Determine the winner
    if (cs % 2 == 0)
    {
        lblTurn.Text = "Computer Won!";
    }
    else
    {
        lblTurn.Text = "You Won!";
    }

    MessageBox.Show(cs.ToString());
}
```

as you can see when the function reaches this line `move = ?;` i want it to wait for the player's move.

i tried to make a **GetPlayerMove()** function to get the player's move and the idea behind that was:

`Boolean pressed = false;`

then

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (pressed== false)
    {
        pressed = true;
    }
}
```

and

```
private int GetPlayerMove()
{
    while(pressed==false)
    {
        if(pressed==true)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return int.Parse(txtMove.Text);
}
```

but the problem is that the while loop does not work how i intended and makes the program to stop responding :/

so... any ideas of how can i make this work?

*also sorry about my English

Comment: you have an infinite loop in `GetPlayerMove()`. If `ds` is `false`, the code will never get out of the loop, as `ds` is never changed inside the loop. What does `ds` stands for ? (having descriptive variable names help other people to look at your code)

Comment: @Pac0
sorry about that it didn't stand for anything so i fixed it (now it's pressed). as you can see the idea was that when i pressed the button the ds(now pressed ) changes its value to true so that the infinite loop (which is waiting for me to press the button) can be broken.

Comment: Ok, that's not how winforms works (and most GUI). If you have some simple code in a function, this code _blocks_ the main thread, which is also the thread that takes care of handling graphical interface. Hence, the window is not responding while the function is executing, making impossible to change the variable _during_ the loop through a button. See for instance the above link from IV, or the many existing tutorials about winforms.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get player's next move in c# WinForms without blocking the UI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75501382/5438626).

Comment: @IV. YES! thank you now i undrestand that i have to work with async functions but iam currently struggling with that.

Comment: Understood! A lot of us _do_ struggle at first when suddenly our code doesn't just go line-by-line in a sequential manner! Even so, understanding the [await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await) operator is going to give you a really good option for solving the issue you're having. My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75503437/5438626) on that thread comes with a [repo](https://github.com/IVSoftware/async-chess-game-loop.git) you can clone and run if that might help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get player's next move in c# WinForms without blocking the UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75501382/how-to-get-players-next-move-in-c-sharp-winforms-without-blocking-the-ui)

Answer (score 0):

If that's the pattern you're trying to go with, you need to use `async` functions. Specifically, you need to have an `async` function that returns your move, so the question mark in your code becomes simply:

```
// instead of: move = ?;
move = await GetPlayerMove();
```

There are many ways to implement this helper, but one simple way is to hook up an event to whatever thing triggers the player move (an image, a button, etc) and have it trigger a `TaskCompletionSource` with a result that you can return in the `GetPlayerMove` helper.

Comment: iam not too familiar with the async functions... imean i didn't get the part: 'TaskCompletionSource' with a result that you can return in the 'GetPlayerMove' helper.
could you please explain further?

so you mean i should have a TaskCompletionSource under my button's event handler?

Comment: TCS is a helper, it's used as a field in your class and has a `SetResult` method that triggers your `await` with the selected result (in this case your player move, whatever it is). It also has a `Task` property, which is what you `await` to get the player move.